# Android listview zoom in can't scroll left and right

Tags: android, listview

I have listview load about 50 images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listViewImg">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

in activity , this code zoom listview

```
final ListView lvi = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewImg);

    try {
        XmlPullParserImg parser = new XmlPullParserImg();
        imgList = parser.parse(getAssets().open(get_xml));
        BinderDataImg binderdata = new BinderDataImg(this, imgHashmap);
        lvi.setAdapter(binderdata);

    }catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FloatingActionButton fa1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fa1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        float x1 = lvi.getScaleX();
        float y1 = lvi.getScaleY();
        lvi.setScaleX(x1 * 2);
        lvi.setScaleY(y1 * 2);
    }
    });
```

I can zoom in and zoom out listview.
when zoom in, I can scroll listview up and down, and image bigger than layout.
but I can't scroll it to left and right ( or move left or right )
sorry for my bad English
thank for reading

Comment: Show your java ListViewAdapter code. It is not possible entirely to resolve this only with your layouts xml code

Comment: I was update in my post

Answer (score 0):

set width of all layout and listView to wrap_content instead of match_parent